# Minimum supported floor weight in the UK

Tags: floor, structural

I live on the second floor of a small block of flats in the UK. To my surprise the floors between levels in the building are wooden and not concrete, as is usual here.

I purchased [a large flat pack wardrobe](https://www.wayfair.co.uk/furniture/pdp/brayden-studio-tengan-2-door-sliding-wardrobe-bryd1318.html) and installed it in my bedroom. It was VERY heavy. The entire thing weighs 151.5kg (334lbs) according to the website, and I know from constructing it that about 75kg (165lbs) of that weight is the mirrored-front sliding doors alone.

It's so much heavier than I was expecting and I can hear the creak slightly as I walk past it. It has a 60cm x 180cm footprint (with at least half the weight centred toward the aforementioned front-mirrored doors).

So now I'm concerned about loading it up with heavy items...

**Question:** What's the minimum floor weight per sq/m a building should be able to support safely? Ie. What are the legal regulations (assuming my flat was built to them!). The building was apparently constructed in 2006. Hopefully I'm worrying about nothing :) Thanks.

Comment: A floor should hold almost anything that regular people would put into a room.  Extra heavy objects(big steel safes, hot tubs) might need more support.  A person walking around should not make anything "move".  A Sumo wrestler jumping up and down might.  Explain moving better in your question.

Comment: @knowitall Yep, I know that. Especially in the warmer parts of your country. However in this very humid climate, larger buildings, especially modern ones, tend to be concrete. (Although it might just be cheaper to construct, I don't know.)

Comment: @crip659 Updated my question. I mean move very slightly. Maybe a few mm. I've lived in properties where a bus going by outside can make the room shake, so I don't agree that it would take a Sumo wrestler in the building to make things move :)

Comment: Usually objects that have some weight to them tend to dampen vibrations.  It is usually the lighter weight non solid(cheap tables) that will pick up movement from a person walking around.   Cement is solid, but breaks fast, wood might bend some first before breaking.  What is your floor covering/s?  Something soft like carpet or hard like wood/tile.

Comment: @crip659 In the bedroom it's laminate flooring with [this underlay](https://www.ukflooringdirect.co.uk/accessories-flooring-underlay-cushion-heat-flow-underlay) underneath (which would account for some of slight movement). The rest of the flat is hardwood flooring.

Comment: average is 30 pounds per square foot, up to 50 pounds.

Comment: Furniture like that is always going to go at the edge of a room. If that's a supporting wall [which it ought to be] then your simple calculations go out the window. Stores wouldn't sell something that is likely to go right through the floor if you don't do some clever calculations first - because one in ten customers would not actually do that, they'd just put it in & then sue when it fell through the floor.

Comment: @Tetsujin It is against a supporting wall, as you say. (The outside wall of the building.) It's a shame the front of the thing is so heavy, though. As I say,  at least 75KG (165lbs) is at the front of it due to the mirrored doors.

Comment: Compare the weight of those mirrored doors, @Chuck, sitting stationary 30-45cm from the wall compared to your weight (75Kg isn't unusual for an adult male) walking around in the middle of the room. Now which one are you worried about?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, but me standing next to the warddrobe has to be close to 500lbs/230KG (150KG warddrove + me 80KG)... And that's without it filled with things.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote an clear, concise question like this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some math.

Typical floor can carry 30 pound per square foot load.

You have 12 square foot furniture with 300 pounds weight.

The floor can carry 12x30 = 360 pounds

Let's hope you have a 50 pounds per square foot floor type, or some kind of supporting wall under it.

**Do not panic just yet.**

Go to store and get 3/4 or 1 inch thick plywood (the laminated kind) they come in standard size 4x8 feet. Paint it nicely to match the floor or cabinet.

Now you have increased the weight distribution are to 32 feet.

Comment: By your calculations I am not allowed to stand on that floor, 200+ pounds and both feet fit in 1 sq. ft.

Comment: "Now you have increased the weight distribution area to 32 feet." Can you explain how you got to 32 square feet?

Comment: @Chuck `4*8=32`?